# Objective-C : Auto Update Label text

Tags: objective-c, label, ibaction, uipickerviewcontroller

I am new to Objective-C and i need your help! In the code that you will see below, my labels pick data from a picker view. I would like instead of using a "calculate" IBAction, to have my "chargeLabel.text" updated in real time as soon as the user changes a value in the picker view.

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
float floatTime;
if ([typeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NiMH"])
{
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5;
} else {
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.4;
}
int intHourhs=(floatTime);
float floatHours=(intHourhs);
float floatMinutes=(floatTime-floatHours)*60;
NSString *stringTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hours: %.0i Minutes: %.0f", intHourhs, floatMinutes];
chargeLabel.text=stringTotal;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` Protocol.
Then, perform whatever you want in `didSelectRow` method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    ...
    //here your code

}
```

Check [UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html)

**EDIT:** I just realized that your accessing `value` property of `chargerSlider` if it is a `UISlider` you don't need to implement any delegate, just assing your IBAction to the `Value Changed` selector of the slider in IB.

Answer (score 1):

Set yourself up as the delegate of UIPickerView, and implement this method: `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent`
When this method get called, simply call `[self calculate:nil];`